# send EMS messages using smsj api

Tags: java, sms, ems

I am new to java programming. I have used [**smsj api**](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/) to send messages from pc to mobile through a gsm modem. I have succesfully been able to send plain text messages using `SmsSender.sendTextSms(msg, reciever, sender)` as well as unicode messages using `SmsSender.sendUnicodeTextSms("smsj हिन्दी मेसेज", reciever);`.

They say it supports EMS messages too. I am trying to send picture messages (black and white), and audio clips through this. But i cannot figure out how to do this.

The [**documentation**](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/class-use/SmsMessage.html#org.marre.sms.ems) shows that there is a class `EmsMessage` that implements `SmsMessage` But i couldn't find any details on how to use it. I have also gone through its forum but again cant find any solution.

Hoping someone could guide me on this.

this is my code for sending text messages..

```
public class SendMessage  {

    public void send() {
    try{
        SmsSender smsSender = SmsSender.getGsmSender("COM14");
            String msg ="smsj test message";        
            String reciever = "919790968633"; 
            String sender ="919176968289";      
            smsSender.connect();

            smsSender.sendTextSms(msg, reciever, sender);  //simple text message

                   smsSender.sendUnicodeTextSms("smsj हिन्दी मेसेज", reciever); //unicode message

            smsSender.disconnect();

    } catch(IOException i){
        i.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("i");
    } catch(SmsException s){
        s.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("s");
    }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SendMessage app = new SendMessage();
        app.send();
    }


}
```

i tried this code for sending ems message.. but it seems to be wrong.

```
     EmsMessage ems = new EmsMessage();
     ems.addText(msg);
     SmsMessage sms ;
     sms=ems;
     smsSender.sendSms(sms, reciever, sender);
```

i get this error message:

```
60 [main] INFO org.marre.sms.transport.gsm.SerialComm - >> AT+CMGF=0    
261 [main] INFO org.marre.sms.transport.gsm.SerialComm - << 
261 [main] INFO org.marre.sms.transport.gsm.SerialComm - << OK
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.marre.sms.transport.gsm.GsmTransport.send(GsmTransport.java:175)
    at org.marre.SmsSender.sendSms(SmsSender.java:551)
    at org.marre.SendMessage.send(SendMessage.java:44)
    at org.marre.SendMessage.main(SendMessage.java:58)
```

Can anyone help me what is the correct syntax of using this EmsMessage and SmsMessage class?

Comment: definitely you are not new to Java

Comment: @Yohan i have basic knowledge of java. whatever i have implemented till now is by following various links on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/ems/EmsMessage.html here you have needed documentation

[addElement](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/ems/EmsMessage.html#addElement%28org.marre.sms.ems.EmsElement%29) should add graphics, movies etc..

[addText](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/ems/EmsMessage.html#addText%28java.lang.String%29) this should add text

Comment: i have gone through these documents...  [http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/ems/EmsElement.html](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/ems/EmsElement.html)  and  [http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/ems/EmsPictureElement.html](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/ems/EmsPictureElement.html)    but could not understand how to implement these in the  code.

Comment: @newtoandroid yes, your right. Are there any methods in this class that are present in source code, and are not present in the docs? Maybe it's just javadoc that is broken.... Or this project has 0 capabilieties to handle EMS

Comment: According to me, i think its just that there are no examples given at all. Hence it is getting difficult to code.   the javadoc seems to be fine.